# React - How to add suffix to input element that follows user input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Before input
[image: Before input]

After input
[image: Afterinput]

The suffix will move with the text.

Comment: You need to create a custom element in a way that the % should be added as a pseudo element to the wrapper of input

Comment: @AbinThaha `input` doesn’t allow `::before` or `::after` pseudo elements

Comment: Sure, I meant a custom component where input will be wrapped inside a div or span and you need to add a pseudo element to that or add an additional span to display the sign

Comment: I agree. A custom component with pseudo elements is the best way to do this.

Comment: but how to make it move with the text?

Comment: You will require to adjust the width of the input text dynamically based on the text input

Comment: I don’t think an input is capable of resizing according to the text content?

Comment: @evolutionxbox even if it was capable, that's not the right solution. i really can't figure this one out. any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet uses the idea of an after pseudo element (here on the label with the input) to show the % sign.

It uses a monospace font for the digits (and % sign and if used the decimal point). A plain text input type is used, with checking in Javascript. CSS variables are set depending on the number of characters, using the 'ch' CSS unit so we aren't subject to random differences in character width.

Some rudimentary checking of the number is done - you'll probably want to add more and at the moment it assumes you want a percentage between 0 and 100 inclusive (including decimals) but of course this can be changed to allow a wider range.

```js
const label = document.querySelector('label');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
let prevStr = '0';

input.addEventListener('keyup', function (){
  const str = input.value;
  const length = str.length;
  number = Number(str);
  if (0 <= number && number <= 100) {
    input.style.setProperty('--numchs', length);
    prevStr = str;
    label.style.setProperty('--message', '');
  }
  else {
    input.value = prevStr;
    label.style.setProperty('--message', (number > 0) ? '"Number would be too big - character ignored"' : '"Only numerical characters allowed"');
  }
  
});
```

```css
label {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: Courier, monospace;
  position: relative;
  width: auto; 
  --number: '0';
  min-width: 2.5ch;
  --message: '';  
}

label::before {
  content: var(--message);
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: red;
}
label::after {
  content: '%';
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: -1.5ch;
  z-index: 1;
}

input {
  --numchs: 1;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: Courier, monospace;
  width: calc((var(--numchs) + 1.5) * 1ch);
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-right: 1px;
}
```

```html
<label><input value="0"/></label>
```

I wasn't sure whether you wanted a fixed-width input or an expanding one. The snippet here expands, but to have a fixed one the position of the % sign could be ascertained through a CSS calc depending on the number of characters typed.

UPDATE: a fixed length input is required so this snippet is as above except the position of the % is determined by the number of characters typed and positioned from the left of the label.

```js
const label = document.querySelector('label');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
let prevStr = '0';

input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  const str = input.value;
  const length = str.length;
  const number = Number(str);
  if (0 <= number && number <= 100) { // set the test to whatever you want - or just test that it is actually a number
    label.style.setProperty('--numchs', length);
    prevStr = str;
    label.style.setProperty('--message', '');
  } else {
    input.value = prevStr;
    label.style.setProperty('--message', (number > 0) ? '"Number would be too big - character ignored"' : '"Only numerical characters allowed"');
  }

});
```

```css
label {
  --numchs: 1;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: Courier, monospace;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  --number: '0';
  min-width: 2.5ch;
  --message: '';
}

label::before {
  content: var(--message);
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: red;
}

label::after {
  content: '%';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc((var(--numchs) * 1ch));
  z-index: 1;
}

input {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: Courier, monospace;
  width: 30vw;
  /* width set for demo - set it to whatever you want */
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-right: 1px;
}
```

```html
<label><input value="0"/></label>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but yes, I need fixed width input. How to calculate number of typed characters?

Comment: I've put in another snippet which deals with the input being of fixed width.

Comment: Thank you! I've adjusted the code for my case and it works great for numbers, but is there any way to adjust this so it works with generic component where input can by any character, not just number? I have problem because character width differs

Comment: Yes character width differing is a problem. How important is it not to have a monospace font when the user is typing in for your particular use case?

Comment: It's really important. Plus, the font will be changing as well. I looked up measuring length of a text input in pixels to try set it up like that, but even for that solution you need to pass font-size and font-family.

It's probably for the best to divide my generic input component according to the special cases.

Comment: I would do it a different way, take what the user has input on each key press and find its width (probably with an offsetWidth or similar, if necessary on another 'test' element).